# Giving the application some data on launch

Tags: c++, launch

I'm trying to create an application that can receive some data on launch from another program.
For example:

```
Start_App.exe calls Main_App.exe and gives it the current date, all at the same time
(while launching it)

Main_App.exe outputs the date on its console
```

Without the data passed by Start_App the other program can't work correctly or will do something else.
I've been searching for a while but it seems like I'm missing the 
technical names...

Comment: Search for the somewhat-technical name _command line arguments_

Comment: Maybe you could write the data to a file for the other program to read, and then delete the file before the other program exits.

Comment: @Alex Yan: That would be really really bad, what if you want to start two instances at the same time? Or you don't have write access to the filesystem? Or you write the data to the file but then fail to delete it?

Comment: Good points. I'm just throwing ideas out there. Not a pro with C++ yet, making progress though, I'm in high school :)

Comment: If you are looking to get this data from another process you wrote, then look into `Inter-Process Communication` (IPC). This is more complex than command-line args, but also much more powerful. But that is only if this is actually what you need. If you can get by with command line arguments, that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably want to use command-line arguments.
They are passed by writing them out, separated by spaces, directly after the program name.

Like so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "There are " << argc << " arguments:" << endl;

    // Loop through each argument and print its number and value
    for (int nArg=0; nArg < argc; nArg++)
        cout << nArg << " " << argv[nArg] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`argc` is the number of arguments the program received.
`*argv[]` is an array of strings, one for each argument.

If you call the program like this:

```
Program.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

It gives you:

```
There are 3 arguments:
0 arg1
1 arg2
2 arg3
```